# Can't understand constructors

Tags: php, constructor, laravel, laravel-4

I've been watching 'laravel from scratch' by 'Jeffrey Way' at laracasts , and I don't understand how he uses class constructors , and the difference the code makes . Here is my before constructor code:

```
    class PostController extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        return View::make('index')->with('posts',$posts);
    }
```

And this is my after code

```
class PostController extends BaseController
{


    protected $post;

    public function __construct(Post $post) {
        $this->post = $post;
    }


    public function index()
    {    
        $posts = $this->post->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        return View::make('index')->with('posts',$posts);
    }
```

How am I able to access the Post class and It's static functions with methods as in

```
$this->post
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A classes constructor is called when a new instance of that class is created (when you call new PostController), all he is doing here is setting a protected property on the object and using dependency injection to pass an instance of that dependency to the __construct method.

In Laravel (and MVC in general), Controllers will be constructed by the framework when a route matches an action on that controller, and with the IoC container, type-hinting the dependency and adding a service provider is enough for Laravel to resolve the dependency.

You may need to understand the Eloquent Facades, when you call a static method on an Eloquent class, it will construct a new instance of that class and call the method on the instance (rather than statically), so

```
Post::all(); // is the same as
(new Post)->all();

class Test
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    echo 'Constructor was called';
  }
}

$test = new Test(); // Constructor was called
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected $post;

public function __construct(Post $post) {
    $this->post = $post;
}
```

Construct is used when this class is first called, so generally a constructor is used to set data on first instance.

This construct can only be initiated via a class of POST passing a $post var, it then assigns the protected property the object of $post.

It can then be used via you index function

Does that help at all?

Comment: But i have automatic resolution on laravel 4 , which automatically injects the necessary values, My doubt is as to the $this variable and how it can access the post class via a method as in '$this->post'